# Get the timestamp of a folder using ANT build.xml

Tags: apache, ant, build, build.xml

Trying to get the timestamp of a results folder and print it, but unfortunately the following code is not working properly,

```
<property name="timestamponresults" value="${dir}/Results"/> 
           <a:fileutil file="${timestamponresults}" property="results_date"> 
               <a:lastmodified format="yyyy-MM-dd"/> 
           </a:fileutil> 
    <echo message="timestamp on results folder is ${results_date}"</echo>
```

it shows the following error,
The prefix "a" for element "a:fileutil" is not bound,Please suggest if there are any other alternatives

Comment: check there where you got the idea of a:fileutil from and check the complete text there, it probably will show a namespace for a: and/or what to install to use it

Comment: The "fileutil" task is a 3rd party ANT extension. You need to read the plugin documentation to discover the correct namespace to declare. For more information on ANT namespace support see https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/namespace.html